# Lightning:recordForm - changing the owner in edit mode

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, owner

I am using lightning:recordForm on my component that is displaying some case data along with the Owner. It's not possible to edit the owner, like it is on the standard one. Is there any way around this?

fields are: CaseNumber,Status,OwnerId,AccountId,Subject,Description

[image]

```
$A.createComponent(
        "lightning:recordForm",
        {
            "aura:id":"caseCompact",
            "recordId":cmp.get("v.recordId"),
            "recordTypeId":cmp.get("v.recordTypeId"),
            "objectApiName":"Case",
            "mode":"view" ,
            "fields":cmp.get("v.fields"),
            "columns":"2",
            "onsuccess": cmp.getReference("c.handleSuccessAction"),
            "oncancel": cmp.getReference("c.handleCancelAction")
        },
        function(newForm, status, errorMessage){
            //Add the new button to the body array
            if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                cmp.set("v.body", [newForm]);
            }
            else if (status === "INCOMPLETE") {
                console.log("No response from server or client is offline.")
                // Show offline error
            }
            else if (status === "ERROR") {
                console.log("Error: " + errorMessage);
                // Show error message
            }
        }
    );
```

Comment: your component seems to indicate 'view' mode

Comment: even edit mode will not bring the change owner button.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs: "Fields that have a spanning relationship aren't supported by lightning:recordForm. The fields specified must be associated with the same objectApiName. A field such as Contact.Account.Ownership is a cross-object reference between the Contact object and the Account object, and can't be displayed in the form."

[Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordForm/documentation)